# Apple Clang on Debian8.1

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

Recently I'm porting Apple Clang-700.1.81 to debian 8.1. I have successfuly build clang with

```
cmake ../llvm -DLLVM_TARGET_TO_BUILD="X86" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr" -DDLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE="x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0"
Make clang -j8 -s 2>Logs
```

CC Complier:gcc-4.9
CXX complier:g++-4.9

Coming out with default target x86_64-apple-darwin3.16.0-amd64

Is there any thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally found the solution for this one.

Make sure install all these plugin.

```
gcc-4.9 g++-4.9-multilib gcc-4.9-multilib gobjc automake autoconf bison flex libtool python-dev libxml2-dev
```

> Building clang-700.0.81 on Unix system

There might be some bug fix, these are what I have done.

1. Delete source file CFString.cpp or move out from the directory.
2. disable SourceManager just comment those code that cause compiler error.
3. "brace-initialization" add additional curly brackets to fix it.

> Building clang-703.0.31 on Unix system

clang-703.0.31 do not need any configuration as clang-700.0.81 does.

Patch clang-703.0.31 with this code to enable preprocessor to dump the right version of clang.

```
src/tools/clang/lib/Basic/Version.cpp    
@@ -112,6 +112,9 @@
           OS << LLVMRepo << ' ';
         OS << LLVMRev << ')';
       }
    +  OS << " (";
    +  OS << 'clang-703.0.31';
    +  OS << ')';
       return OS.str();
     }
```

Finally build clang-700.0.81 or clang-703.0.31 with these arguments

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../src -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=False -DCOMPILER_RT_INCLUDE_TESTS=False -DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER=Address
```

Fix me if I am wrong